# Asking for a generating function for an arithmetic sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

For fixed integer $n\geq1$, let $c_m(n)$ be the number of divisors $d$ of $m$ such that $n<d\leq 2n$. Here is an experimental generating function for which I ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
> $$\sum_{m\geq1}c_m(n)\,q^m=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\binom{n}k_q}{\binom{n+k}k_q}\frac{q^{\binom{k+1}2+nk}}{(1-q^k)}$$
> where $\binom{a}b_q$ are the usual $q$-binomial or Gaussian polynomials.

Comment: Why such conjecture?

Comment: How much empirical evidence do you have for this conjecture?

Comment: Left hand side obviously equals $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{q^{n+i}}{1-q^{n+i}} $, but you experimentally found a much more involved sum. Quite unusual.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: it came off like this: I was playing around the RHS for other reasons and simplification of it lead me to the LHS as you wrote it. All I did now to your LHS is interpret as a divisor function.